# The degree and minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ of $j\sqrt{2}$

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials, minimal-polynomials

What is the degree and minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ of $j\sqrt{2}$, where $j$ denotes $-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i$, a primitive thrid root of unity?

I see that $(j\sqrt{2})^6=8$.  Then $P(j\sqrt{2})=0$ with $P=X^6-8$. Can we say that $P$  is irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Actually, $(i\sqrt2)^2=-2$...

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I suspect he uses $j$ for the primitive cube root of unity. I have seen it done. Mad notation.

Comment: In that case, note that $x^6-8$ factors as a quadratic and a quartic from the $a^3-b^3$ identity.

Comment: Then use the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1498310/minimal-polynomial-of-alpha-sqrt-2e-frac2-pi-i3) to show that the quartic is irreducible.

Comment: Or rather, [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1118762/357390).